# Getting item price with Web Scraping

Tags: python, web, scrape, price

I would like to make a *Python* script, but unfortunately, when I want to check the price, I get `NONE` instead of the price itself (or US$00.00 if I change the code).
I found a lot of examples for it, where the *HTML* is with `id`, but I do not know how I should do it with `class`.

What I have so far:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = 'https://www.banggood.com/BlitzWolf-BW-LT32-2M-USB-RGB-TV-Strip-Light-Kit-Sync-with-TV-Screen-Color-3-Sides-Cover-for-TV-Vivid-RGB-Color-Lighting-Effect-and-Dual-Simple-Control-p-1785284.html?akmClientCountry=HU&channel=facebookads&utm_source=facebookads&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=app-dpa-all-ww-sm-afpur180-0407_prdshare_msg&utm_content=suki&utm_design=-&fbclid=IwAR3cAovrze4opttuwwpUxnXZ6dkRjhau3RqmDqASPW0mSEOI8sJgn9Cqss8&_branch_match_id=850392564428961100&cur_warehouse=CN&ID=45764'

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    title = soup.find("span",{"class":'product-title-text'}).get_text()
    price = soup.find("span",{"class":'main-price'}).get_text()


converted_price = price[0:5]

print(converted_price)
print(title)
```

Comment: Please include a sample of the HTML and explain which parts you want to extract.

Comment: The item is cheaper now, and i need the 26.88 

<div class="product-price">
                        <span class="sign-price" style="display: none;"></span>
                        <span class="main-price" oriprice-range="0-0" oriprice="26.88">US$26.88</span>
                        <span class="old-price" oriprice="49.99" style="display: inline;">US$49.99</span>
                        <span class="discount" style="display: inline;">-46%</span>
                        <span class="vip-text" style="display: none;"></span>
                        <div class="right-price">

Comment: Thanks for the update, but please [edit] your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` has very minimal use to web scraping when the website is using Javascript and changes dynamically. Most of the websites these days you Javascript making it difficult to scrape data. One of the alternate option is to use `Selenium`.

If you have already used `Selenium` then directly jump to the code block below. If not, follow the instructions below.

1. Check the Chrome version you are using in `About Chrome` under the options menu(top right corner of the browser).
2. Go to [this](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) website and download the same version of the driver.
3. Create a folder `C:\webdrivers` and copy the downloaded driver into this folder.
4. Copy the file path `C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe` and add it to *PATH* in the `environment variables` (

Now execute the code below :

```
from selenium import webdriver

opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# The below line will make your browser run in background when uncommented
# opts.add_argument('--headless')
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options= opts, executable_path = 'C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("https://www.banggood.in/BlitzWolf-BW-LT32-2M-USB-RGB-TV-Strip-Light-Kit-Sync-with-TV-Screen-Color-3-Sides-Cover-for-TV-Vivid-RGB-Color-Lighting-Effect-and-Dual-Simple-Control-p-1785284.html?akmClientCountry=HU&channel=facebookads&utm_source=facebookads&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=app-dpa-all-ww-sm-afpur180-0407_prdshare_msg&utm_content=suki&utm_design=-&_branch_match_id=850392564428961100&cur_warehouse=CN&ID=45764")

prices = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('main-price')

for price in prices:
    print(price.text)
driver.quit()
```

Output :

```
₹1,712.63
```

For more details  about `Selenium` go through the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), it's a quite impressive module!

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast help and the detailed answer!

Comment: Error: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_class_name'

Comment: In the latest `Selenium` update they've combined all the identifier methods into one. So by replacing `driver.find_elements_by_class_name()` with `driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "main-price")` the error can be rectified.